# How to render into different layers and then combine them together with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am rendering several layers, which cannot be rendered on just one frame buffer because the modifications would affect all the other layers under it.

How can I render these layers separately in such a way that I can combine them into one final layer? The layers would be rendered with transparency, so when combining them, they would be blended accordingly to all the layers below.

I am currently using FBO to offscreen render them all in one layer, but as I said above, it's not going to work very well when the top-most layer affects all the bottom layers as well.

So how can I combine two (or more? (whichever way is faster)) FBO's (or some better method for FBO?) together as efficiently as possible? Currently I could render them one by one, put into my RAM and then combine them per pixel basis myself, but that seems like a slow method.

What's the fastest way doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Use a 2D texture array. Each layer of the array is one render layer.

Render each layer into its own color attachment texture layer (you can switch FBO color attachment at any time), using `glFramebufferTexture3D` you can select the target layer.

Then in a fragment shader combine the layers of the 2D array texture as desired.

You can also use multi-rendertargets by binding different texture layers to different render targets.

Comment: Is it really necessary to keep all the layers in the memory at same time? Cant it be done by allocating only two buffers, and then the new buffer will be combined to the first buffer each time, until no more layers need to be rendered so the first buffer will contain the resulting image? For example 8 layers would use 50% of my GFX card memory (2048x2048x4 size buffers).

Comment: @Rookie: You can of course do the rendering in a `foreach(layer) {render layer; composite layer into destination}` loop. However this puts a synchronization point for each composition so overall performance may degrade.

Answer (score 3):

You can use MRT (multiple render targets). You will need to create and bind framebuffer (seems you already know how to do it), then attach several textures to it like

```
glFramebufferTexture2DEXT ( GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texA, 0 );
glFramebufferTexture2DEXT ( GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texB, 0 );
```

Here I attached two textures (`texA` & `texB`, which were created using `glGenTextures`), as color attachments number `0` and `1`. Then you just write your colors in shader using not `gl_FragColor` output variable, but rather `gl_FragData[0]` for the first color attachment and `gl_FragData[1]` for the second.

You can then use second pass to combine images stored in `texA` and `texB` textures.

P.S. these are the function calls for OpenGL 2. If you use OpenGL 3, the functions calls are similar (just without `EXT`), but you'll need to specify outputs for your shader manually. I can post the solution for this if necessary.

Comment: So this method requires me to create a shader for each amount of layers separately? The amount of layers is variable in my case. Is this possible without shaders? I was thinking something like, using two buffers, and combining second buffer to the first buffer each time, so finally the first buffer is the resulting image.

Comment: As you already mentioned in your question, it'll be a slow method. Shaders are a common way to do complex computations or effects, so it's better to use them. In modern graphical API's (since OpenGL 3) you will need shaders even to render a simple triangle, so it's better to familiarize yourself with them.

Comment: About the variable number of shaders: the best way is to write separate shaders for each number of layers (i.e. a shader for 2 layers, a shader for 3 layers etc.). The other way is to write it in one shader using conditional `if`. I can't say which one will be faster, so I'd suggest trying it, but keep in mind, that it's not the best practice to use conditionals in shaders (GPU's are not designed to be universal computational devices, they are slow on processing conditional jumps)

Comment: I'm more worried about memory consumption since this program could be ran simultaneously at multiple processes. Do you know how much slower would it be if i only used 2 buffers? About the variable number of shaders; i think i could do it by generating the shader code before i run the shader, i guess it only needs some repetition in the code, so it shouldnt be too hard. But still, as i said, im more worried about memory use here.

Comment: Generating shader code on the fly might be a good idea, but it is better to have some frequently used cases in separate shaders to save time needed to compile them. Then, if you get a very uncommon case, you can modify shader code and compile it, but most of the time you'll have an already compiled shader. As for memory consumption, you can always check it using gDebugger. I don't have any experience in GPU's memory profiling, so I have no idea about possible memory bottlenecks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but, you can create a layer management sorted by levels. Then, only you've to draw the first layer to last layer and, if you have the right blend function, you can achieve the desired alpha effect ... also, you can control the total alpha over all scenes. It's important to clear **DEPTH BIT BUFFER** to render every layer  in independently manner.

A bit of pseudocode of this idea can be the following,

```
Total Alpha = 0.9
For l in layer_list // render layers
    // clear depth bit (important before render every layer)
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BIT_BUFFER)   

    // render all objects layer of layer 'l' with alpha = layer_alpha * total_alpha
    renderLayer(l, TotalAlpha*l.getAlpha())

End For
```

Comment: I've tried that and unfortunately does not do the trick... for some reason some objects will simply not render, don't know why.